# How to remove the first number of a float if it's lower than 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx

I want to remove the first number of float values if they are lower than 1

In the "OPS" table section I got the sum of OBP + SLG (their values are being taken from a DB).

[image]

Code:

```
<td>{props.player.OBP}</td>
<td>{props.player.SLG}</td>
<td>
  {(parseFloat(props.player.OBP) + parseFloat(props.player.SLG)).toFixed(3)}
</td>
```

It's all good, except that I would like the values in the OPS section to not display the first number if it's a zero, just like in the OBP and SLG sections.

Full code in this link: https://www.paste.org/111713

Answer (score 2):

After calling `toFixed`, call `.replace` to replace `^0` (the start of the string followed by 0) with nothing:

```
.toFixed(3).replace(/^0/, '')
```

Comment: OP should be aware the conversion to a string here - lack of mathematical ops without type conversion back to float.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about the replace method!